# Finding Out if an Amazon S3 Bucket is a Website in Ruby

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

Amazon recently allowed S3 buckets to be enabled as websites. Using the aws-s3 gem or something similar, is there a way to programmatically determine whether a given bucket is enabled as a website or not?

Edit: In addition, if a bucket is indeed a website, how would you obtain the endpoint url?

Comment: Do you have an example website where you know for sure that it is a bucket website? Maybe Amazon puts something in the header.

Comment: Yes, I myself do know if the bucket is a website or not. I'd like to know how to find out programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the REST api to access, and set that option

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/index.html?RESTBucketPUTwebsite.html

in your case use "GET Bucket website"

Extra points:

The endpoint would be just the bucket URL : example-bucket.s3.amazon.com

Comment: Thanks for the response, but your last bit is not always true. For example, my bucket's end url is `mybucket.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com`